# Django Postgres memory leak

Tags: python, django, multithreading, postgresql, memory-leaks

I have a custom Django (v 2.0.0) command to start background job executers in a multi-threaded fashion which seems to give me memory leak issues.

The command can be started like so:

```
./manage.py start_job_executer --thread=1
```

Each thread has a while True loop that picks up jobs from a PostgreSQL table.

In order to pick up the job and change the status atomically I used transactions:

```py
# atomic transaction to temporary lock the db access and to
# get the most recent job from db with column status = pending
with transaction.atomic():
    job = Job.objects.select_for_update() \
        .filter(status=Job.STATUS['pending']) \
        .order_by('created_at').first()
    if job:
        job.status = Job.STATUS['executing']
        job.save()
```

Il looks like the allocated memory by this Django custom command keeps growing.

Using tracemalloc I tried to find what is causing the memory leak by creating a background thread that checks the memory allocation:

```py
def check_memory(self):
        while True:
            s1 = tracemalloc.take_snapshot()
            sleep(10)
            s2 = tracemalloc.take_snapshot()
            for alog in s2.compare_to(s1, 'lineno')[:10]:
                log.info(alog)
```

Finding out the following log:

```sh
01.04.20 13:50:06   operations.py:222: size=23.7 KiB (+23.7 KiB), count=66 (+66), average=367 B
01.04.20 13:50:36   operations.py:222: size=127 KiB (+43.7 KiB), count=353 (+122), average=367 B
01.04.20 13:51:04   operations.py:222: size=251 KiB (+66.7 KiB), count=699 (+186), average=367 B
01.04.20 13:51:31   operations.py:222: size=379 KiB (+68.9 KiB), count=1056 (+192), average=367 B
01.04.20 13:51:57   operations.py:222: size=495 KiB (+60.3 KiB), count=1380 (+168), average=367 B
```

Looks like /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/operations.py:222 does not release memory

The leakage is slow for 1 thread but if I use 8 threads the memory leak is worse:

```sh
01.04.20 13:07:51   operations.py:222: size=68.3 KiB (+68.3 KiB), count=191 (+191), average=366 B
01.04.20 13:08:56   operations.py:222: size=770 KiB (+140 KiB), count=2151 (+390), average=367 B
01.04.20 13:10:07   operations.py:222: size=1476 KiB (+138 KiB), count=4122 (+386), average=367 B

01.04.20 13:36:22   operations.py:222: size=17.3 MiB (+138 KiB), count=49506 (+385), average=367 B

01.04.20 13:48:16   operations.py:222: size=24.5 MiB (+136 KiB), count=69993 (+379), average=367 B
```

This is the code at line 222 in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/operations.py:222:

```py
def last_executed_query(self, cursor, sql, params):
        # http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/cursor.html#cursor.query
        # The query attribute is a Psycopg extension to the DB API 2.0.
        if cursor.query is not None:
            return cursor.query.decode() # this is line 222!
        return None
```

I have no clue how to attack this problem. Any ideas at all?

Posted it here also: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/31419#ticket

I was thinking to maybe fork a new process for every job that needs to be executed, and once finished, the memory would be deallocated with the process itself dying. This would probably work but it seems a little overkill.

Thanks in advance

**UPDATE**

I was using Django 2.0 and I thought to update to Django 3.0.5 (latest stable release), but unfortunately the problem is still there.

Below the new logs:

```sh
01.04.20 20:15:06   operations.py:235: size=977 KiB (+53.9 KiB), count=2750 (+152), average=364 B
01.04.20 20:15:28   operations.py:235: size=1070 KiB (+50.1 KiB), count=3012 (+141), average=364 B
01.04.20 20:15:53   operations.py:235: size=1156 KiB (+43.7 KiB), count=3255 (+123), average=364 B
01.04.20 20:16:19   operations.py:235: size=1245 KiB (+44.7 KiB), count=3507 (+126), average=364 B

01.04.20 20:20:23   operations.py:235: size=2154 KiB (+44.3 KiB), count=6065 (+125), average=364 B
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Django keeps a reference to all executed queries in a ring buffer when `settings.DEBUG = True`

From [`DEBUG` ​documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#debug)

> It is also important to remember that when running with `DEBUG` turned on, Django will remember every SQL query it executes. This is useful when you’re debugging, but it’ll rapidly consume memory on a production server.

Setting `DEBUG = False` should address your issue.

To wipe the ring buffer in situations where it may pose a problem in development:

```
from django.db import reset_queries
if settings.DEBUG:
    reset_queries()
```

Comment: Thank you! A week of debugging later you finally nailed it!

Comment: Is there a way to say Django not to store those SQL queries in a particular function? Or maybe it's possible to manually flush the buffer that stores the queries? The problem is that I want to use all advantages of the debug mode when testing my scripts, but the memory consumption is so huge that my PC runs out of memory.

Comment: @AndreyVolkov I know your comment is almost a year old, but I updated Simon's answer to demonstrate the mechanism for resetting the buffer. I don't know that a way exists to disable it in DEBUG mode, but you could possibly look at the source for the `reset_queries` function and monkeypatch the underlying data structure with a different implementation that just does a `pass` instead of holding it.